# Temp table columns missing when comparing to permanent table columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to compare the temp table columns and permanent table columns to get the columns which were not exists from both tables, however the temp table columns are not exists. I am sure I have created it using the scripts below. When I query the temp table columns using the below query I cannot find any columns. Anyone knows what is wrong?

```
select 
    c.name 
from 
    tempdb.sys.columns c
inner join 
    tempdb.sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
where 
    t.name ='#authors'
```

Table and data

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Authors](
            [Client_Id] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
            [Project_Id] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
            [Person_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
            [Author_Number] [int] NOT NULL,
            [Family_Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
            [First_Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        )

        INSERT INTO Authors (Client_Id, Project_Id, Person_Id, Author_Number, Family_Name, First_Name)
        VALUES ('Client1','TEST1',12345,1,'Giust','Fede')
        INSERT INTO Authors (Client_Id, Project_Id, Person_Id, Author_Number, Family_Name, First_Name)
        VALUES ('Client1','TEST1',12345,2,'Ma','Ke')
        INSERT INTO Authors (Client_Id, Project_Id, Person_Id, Author_Number, Family_Name, First_Name)
        VALUES ('Client2','TEST2',12346,1,'Jones','Peter')
        INSERT INTO Authors (Client_Id, Project_Id, Person_Id, Author_Number, Family_Name, First_Name)
        VALUES ('Client2','TEST2',12346,2,'Davies','Bob')
        INSERT INTO Authors (Client_Id, Project_Id, Person_Id, Author_Number, Family_Name, First_Name)
        VALUES ('Client3','TEST3',12346,3,'Richards','Craig')

SELECT * INTO #authors FROM authors
```

Code

```
select 
    c2.table_name,c2.COLUMN_NAME
from 
    [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] c2
where 
    table_name = 'Authors'
    and c2.COLUMN_NAME NOT in (select c.name 
                               from tempdb.sys.columns c
                               inner join tempdb.sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
                               where t.name ='#authors')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the table in tempdb is not just `#authors`. SQL Server changes the name. In my case the name is `#authors____________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000059`

You can change your query to use `like` to select the right table:

```
select c.name from tempdb.sys.columns c
    inner join tempdb.sys.tables t
 ON c.object_id = t.object_id

where t.name like '#authors%'
```

Comment: @Szymon- Thank you. I will change the name of the permanent table since they have the same name, it will get the columns too from that table.